# Generate a second html page with vite

Tags: html, css, build, vite, rollup

Is there any way that I can generate a second HTML?

I have a Vite + React build, and it generates an `index.html` + a reference to a `index-[hash].css` in the `/build` folder. All good.

I want to have a second, different much smaller `maintenance.html` file in the `/public` folder - and I want it to reference the `index-[hash].css` file as well, hence I cannot simply maintain it in the public folder.

Another possibility would be have it as a second entry point altogether with it's on css in `src`, and generate a separate css for it - and reference that after building.

Any ideas on how I can do this with Vite? Or do I need to rely on other tools?